# Errors from nouveau when installing or booting from live usb

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb

When I try to install or boot Ubuntu from USB I get these errors relating to nouveau:

[image]

```
fifo: write fault ... REGION VIOLATION ... init failed
```

Any possible fixes?

Comment: You need `nomodeset`.

Comment: How do I do this nomodeset ??

Comment: It depends on how you're booting. UEFI: At the first menu with " Try Ubuntu" selected press 'e' and add `nomodeset` to the same line where `quiet splash` is. BIOS/Legacy: At the first menu, after selecting the language, press F6 ans select "nomodeset".

Answer (score 18):

The answer is what @MichaelBay said in the comments. I had this same issue when trying to live boot Linux Mint 18, any of the flavors with an Nvidia 970 GPU.

1. For UEFI boot, press <kbd>e</kbd> when it says “Start Linux/Ubuntu”.
2. Find the line that says `quiet splash`
3. Right after that, add `nomodeset` and then press F10 to boot (or whatever key it instructs you to press).

It should boot Linux now with no graphics drivers, which appears to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd been this problem now (june 2021) and after change bios option Graphic device to UMA Only, I finally got the boot.
My machine is a Lenovo ideapad notebook
Answering just to consult.