# Can't boot installation on desktop with NVIDIA GPU

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, gpu

I'm having trouble installing and booting Ubuntu on a high end laptop with a GPU.  I do the installation from a bootable USB drive.  To get that to work I have to go into the boot menu and set the nomodeset option as described here ([Errors from nouveau when installing or booting from live usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947830/errors-from-nouveau-when-installing-or-booting-from-live-usb)).

The problem is that the newly installed image hangs just after login.  No doubt its  hanging because of issues with the GPU driver just like installer was hanging until I set the nomodeset option.  The problem is that I can't figure out a way to boot into a safe mode state so I can either set a nomodeset option or update the drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the option right in the GRUB boot menu. After turning on your computer, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to display the GRUB screen, press <kbd>E</kbd> to enter the edit menu. Here, scroll down to the line having `linux` and add the `nomodeset` parameter right to the end of that line.

If you're able to successfully log in, then open a Root Terminal, and open `/etc/default/grub`  with your favourite editor. Add `nomodeset` inside the quotes to the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` (create that line if it doesn't exist), and then run `sudo update-grub`.

Let me know if I'm missing any details here.

Comment: Can you add the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to create if it didn't exist?

Comment: Yes. Of course. Just add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"`.

Comment: That sounds right, but I can't get to the GRUB screen.  Shift doesn't get me there, ctrl-alt-F1 doesn't get me there.  It always just continues to an ubuntu login screen (which hangs as soon as you try to type in the password box)

Comment: As you have accepted my answer, I assume you solved the issue you just commented.