# nouveau : tmr: stalled at fffffff

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, usb

I installed my Ubuntu 19.10 on a USB stick(I use UEFI boot).At first it could boot very well.But when I tried to shut down Ubuntu 19.10 ,it gave a PCIe Bus Error.Just like this:

pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer (I can't remember the id)

pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: [20] UnsUpReq

So I tried to add pci = nomsi parameter in grub.It worked. But when I tried to boot Ubuntu 19.10 ,it gave a new error:

nouveau 000:01:00.0 tmr:  stalled at ffff

nouveau 000:01:00.0 tmr:  stalled at ffff

nouveau 000:01:00.0 tmr:  stalled at ffff

(I don't know how many f there were,and I did not change any graphics card configuration)

It's difficult for me to slove this question.How can I do? HELP!HELP!HELP!

Comment: I can't enter the system right now...

Comment: Please excuse that I can't speak English well, thx :)

Comment: Try bootoption nomodeset https://askubuntu.com/questions/947830/errors-from-nouveau-when-installing-or-booting-from-live-usb

Comment: OK , Let me have a try :)